# Generic Tree father of a node code or algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, generics, tree

I've got an assignment that asks for me to read a generic tree from a txt, allocate the tree in memory then do a series of operations such as removing a node, removing a sub tree, listing the children of a node, listing the descendants of a node and, the one I'm having trouble with, listing the father of a node. The language used is C. There can be elements of the C++ language that aren't "shortcuts",such as using classes.

I'm using this structure for generic tree:

```
typedef struct genTree
    {
        char info;
        struct genTree* first; //points to the first child of a node
        struct genTree* next; //points to the first sibling of a node
    }tgt;
    typedef tgt* pgt;
```

Which means that the father of a node points to it's first child, then this child points to it's siblings.

I came up with this function that always returns the root of the tree:

```
pgt find_father(pgt root, char SON_PARAM)    
{    
        pgt son, father;
        if(root == NULL) return NULL;
        if(root->info == SON_NODE) return root;
        if(root->next != NULL) {
             son = find_father(root->next, SON_NODE);
             return son;
        }
        else {
             father = root;
             son = find_father(root->first, SON_NODE);
             if(son == NULL) return NULL;
             else return son;
        }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it not run or not compile? `genTree*` should be `struct genTree*`

Comment: It runs and exits with failure, exit value 1, fixed the mistyping

Comment: Everywhere. Input parameter too. Please paste in the code you compiled. Including the main() function. What does exit code 1 mean?

Comment: what kind of assigment is `The language used is C. There can be elements of the C++ language that aren't "shortcuts",such as using classes.`

Comment: Our teacher let's us use c++ simple commands such as std::cin and std::cout, or boolean values

Comment: awfull... what purpose?

Comment: @MadPhysicist sorry not to post the whole compiled code, but it's because it's written completely in Portuguese, so for the sake of others, i just translated this part of the code, but believe me, everything else works.

Comment: @itwasntpete I don't know, maybe it's because c++ has many "built-in" features, such as Stacks, Lists and Queues.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Apparently it means that it did some "invalid operation"
(http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)

Comment: Makes sense. No return value for most cases...

Comment: maby [this](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs225/s03/binary_trees/) could help.

Comment: If you're looking for the father of a node, you need the node in question and the root of the tree as parameters, unless you store parent pointers in the tree. What purpose does the `NODE_PARAM` serve? Or are you not actually looking for the father of a node, but the node containing a specific `char`?

Comment: @molbdnilo NODE_PARAM is the node identifier, for instance: I have a tree in which A is the root, B, C and D are the sons of A and E and F are sons of B.

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not have a return statement in all cases. You should return something of type `struct genTree *`. Also, when you set `b->first = find_father(root->next, NODE_PARAM)`, you are effectively overwriting your entire tree. Remember that `b` is not a `struct genTree` but a `struct genTree *`. This means that you are resetting the field `first` in the thing `b` **points** to. Lastly, you must do a depth-first search here because you do not have back-references. The easiest thing would be to introduce a back-reference in `struct genTree`. Assuming I understand what you are trying to do correctly, try this:

```
struct genTree
{
    char info;
    struct genTree* parent; //points to the parent of a node (NULL if root)
    struct genTree* first; //points to the first child of a node
    struct genTree* next; //points to the first sibling of a node
}

struct genTree* find_father(struct genTree* root, char NODE_PARAM)    
{    
        struct genTree* b;
        if(root == NULL) return NULL;  //standard error checking    
        if(root->info == NODE_PARAM) return root->parent;    
        b = find_father(root->first, NODE_PARAM);
        if(b == NULL)     
        {    
            b = find_father(root->next, NODE_PARAM);
        }
        return b;
}
```

In this case, an exit code of 1 is probably caused by the fact that the processor is trying to read a trash return value. This would be OK if it was a number, but a trash pointer (even if it is just NULL), is usually a problem.

Comment: This code return the node, NODE_PARAM. I'm wishing to return the father of NODE_PARAM

Comment: @Pedro Not according to `if(root->info == NODE_PARAM) return root`. If by father you mean the node that contains the char, that is what this function is doing. Otherwise you will have to use a global pointer if you use recursion.

Comment: how should a global pointer be used? and by father i mean the node that is "directly above" the node that contais the char. Sorry i couldn't express my thoughts any better :/

Comment: A global pointer would be the way to go it inserting a back-reference into the struct is not an option.

Comment: So let me think about it for a minute.